# Average function not working corre

Tags: c++, average

I am working on a program for my C++ class, which the objective is to create a function to find the highest, lowest, mean and median of a vector and return it as a struct. I have every function working so far but the issue I am running into is my mean function does not return the correct value for the mean.

```
#include "std_lib_facilities_4.h"

struct VALUES{
    int lowest;
    int highest;
    int median;
    int mean;
};


VALUES actions(vector <int> a){
    VALUES b;
    int lowest = 100;
    int highest = 0;
    int total;
    int median;
    int mean;
    for(int i = 0; i<a.size(); i++){
        if(a[i]<lowest){
            lowest = a[i];
        }
        if(a[i]>highest){
            highest = a[i];
        }
        total = total + a[i];
    }
    median = a[a.size()/2];
    mean = total/11;
    b.lowest = lowest;
    b.highest = highest;
    b.median = median;
    b.mean = mean;

    return b;   
}


int main(){
    vector <int> original;
    for(int i = 0; i<11; i++){
        original.push_back(i);
    }
    //actions(original);
    VALUES ending;
    ending = actions(original);
    cout<< "Lowest " << ending.lowest<< "\n";
    cout<< "Highest " << ending.highest<< "\n";
    cout<< "Median " <<ending.median<< "\n";
    cout<< "Mean " <<ending.mean<< "\n";
}
```

I have looked over this multiple times for any small errors but I have been unable to find one. The answer displays 2983 as the mean when running the program.

Comment: The median is the value in the "middle" of a sorted list of values if there are an odd number of values, and the average of the 2 middle most values there are an odd number of values. SInce you have 11 values you are ok this time provided the list is sorted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initialize `total` to zero:

```
int total = 0;
```

It is currently uninitialised and could be anything.

A couple of other things to watch out for:

- Your median calculation relies on the vector being sorted
- If there is an even number of values the median is usually defined to be the mean of the two middle values.
- Your calculation of mean should probably be done using floating point and not integers
- It would be good practice to pass the vector to `actions` by const reference, not value.

Comment: Thanks! That was a pretty silly mistake on my part. Still relatively new to programming so the more you learn I guess.

Comment: I recommend you turn up the warning level on your compiler (e.g -Wall in gcc, Level4 in MSVC) and pay attention to any warnings you get. Most compilers can warn you of uninitialized variables.

Answer (score 0):

Total is currently adding to nothing initialized, it could have a rather unpredictable outcome. Change that so that it is initialized to zero, `int total = 0;`.
Also you are setting mean to total divided by 11. Shouldn't it be `mean = total / a.size();`?

Comment: oh yes I originally had it as that but I changed it in order to see if that was creating my error (which was not). I just forgot to change it back.